# Need guidance on UK visitor visa application questions

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I am helping my mother-in-law with her visitor visa application for the UK. This is the new online application process (not the old visa4uk website base).

In the section about **income & expenditure** they have the following question which is confusing me given her circumstances

**What is the total amount of money you spend each month?**

My mother-in-law is unemployed and fully supported by her husband. They run the household out of my father-in-law's salary but she does not explicitly spend any money. What should I write here? Can I leave this as zero and provide an explanation in the covering letter that it is her husband who helps with all the expenses?

Note that she is applying alone and travelling alone. She has done this 2 years ago but the application form back then was different.

Comment: Does your mother in law never ever handle cash or make any purchases at all?

Comment: Think of it as total household expenditures, regardless of how it is funded: food, utilities, mortgage/rent, insurance etc.... everything that is spent each month to support and maintain them. That joint income against expenditures and bank statements are evidence needed to demonstrate financial viability.

Comment: @Giorgio Thanks. I get it now. In terms of evidence, can then we submit salary slips and bank statements of my father-in-law out of whose income these expenditures are happening, even though he is not the applicant himself?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick She does but that is very difficult to calculate isn't it?

Comment: Yes, her husband supports her, use his documentation, as reviewed in this [Q&A on supporting documents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92740/what-supporting-documents-should-i-include-in-my-uk-visa-application)

Answer (score 1):

While your mother-in-law is not employed income of her own, her husband's income supports the entire household and is shared. Respond to the questions in terms of total expenditures, regardless of how it is funded: food, utilities, mortgage/rent, insurance etc., everything that is spent each month to support and maintain them (and anyone else in the household). That joint/shared income against expenditures and bank statements are evidence needed to demonstrate financial viability.

It would be your father-in-law's documents that support her application: his salary slips, bank statements, employment letter, etc.