# Indian student willing to apply for Standard Visitor Visa only for U.K

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, family

I am an Indian passport holder studying currently in China with a valid student visa expiring in next year September and i want to visit UK for tourism and family visit purposes for 3 months approx.

So as a student I want to know What kind of documents will be appropriate to submit to the embassy ? Should i submit the copies of my tuition fee receipt ?

Since i do not have any kind of income my Chinese bank statements just show the proof of my regular monthly expenses provided by my father but not much of savings.So would this be any kind of problem for refusal?

PS : My course that i am studying finishes in 2020 in China so i have to come back to attend my graduation and finish the course.

```
 My brother in law living in UK is going to sponsor my trip and also my parents who applied for UK visa from India also successfully got the UK Visa very recently.
```

and Now its my turn to apply the visa from China to meet them there in my university vacation time.

Any kind of help or suggestions would be most useful for me. Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this Guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page2

Comment: Also related and may be helpful: [What supporting documents should I include in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92740/what-supporting-documents-should-i-include-in-my-uk-visa-application)