# Paternal uncle as sponsor for UK plab 2 visa?

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I guess I have a complicated case..

Well, my dad is a private lawyer and he invests the money earned rather than setting money aside in a bank. So, he has a lot of shares in primary and secondary market, but he hasn't been able to maintain a good bank balance as he takes in hand cash for his services and invests in real estate / share market within little to no time. Therefore, I opted not to show his bank account and put in my paternal uncle as my sponsor.

My paternal uncle has a reputable job in the banking sector and earns close to 6 figures. He has regular transactions coming in and going out of his account and has done the same in last 2 years as well. He has a good travel history to US, Australia, and several places round the globe, where he hasn't overstayed, ever. Now, like his previous transactions, he'll have a huge amount of money in his account from real estate, and it just so happened that it kind of coincided nearing my visa application date.

My query is whether he could back up his transactions for last 3-6 months ( major ones) including the last one in his sponsorship letter and provide in share papers, land ownership documents, etc. OR should I get the bank statements and transactions approved by chartered accountants??

And second query: 
Will shares serve the same/  similar purpose of "liquid assets" as cash in bank and whether i should show in my father as my sponsor instead?

Both of them have acres of land and houses in their names as well..

Please shine some light into this question of mine.

Comment: Your situation is not unique. It is covered by answers such as https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92740/what-supporting-documents-should-i-include-in-my-uk-visa-application and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158

Comment: Thanks.. i will certainly add in the share papers, relevant bills, tax paid certificates!!

Comment: Since i work at a medical college, and it pays cash in hand, will me showing a letter in letterhead stating : 1. I am their employee, i work as a ..., Since ..., Get paid --- every month via cash in hand and 2. Pay slips of last 6 months 3. No objection letter stating Unpaid leave of ~ 2 months suffice or should i attach in my bank accounts ( through which i just trade in shares) as well? TIA

Comment: The British penalize any kind of thing that looks like money laundering. They like the movement of money to be showed by a paper trail and preferably through banks. Cash payments are frowned upon unfortunately. Since you have the pay slips that is what is important. That addresses the problem somewhat. You can add a letter from the school.

Comment: Thanks will do.. huge money needs to be backed by relevant papers.. got it..

Comment: Yes, I'm intending to go extra miles just to do that.. but, in hindsight, sometimes do think if more evidences raise more suspicion ( as if I'm eager or something) .. most of my friends from my country are in the UK, and they have been granted visas no more than 2-3 months back.. still,  I'm trying to make my case extra strong and leave no leaves unturned.. thanks a ton.. i certainly can sleep well now.. 

Comment: Getting paid in cash is fine as long as you turn around and put that cash in the bank. You can then withdraw for living expenses etc. It's about paper trails really.