# How much money do I need to sponsor someone to the UK on visitor visa for 6 months?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, egypt

I’m trying to get my husband to the UK for 6 months. How much money is needed to sponsor this and what is required?

Comment: Your current series of questions feel like you want your husband to move to the UK now and arrange a spouse visa when he is there. I fear the visa officials will assume the same. So any long term visa or stay will be seen as suspect.

Answer (score 3):

There is no set amount. An applicant needs to show that their sponsor has sufficient resources to support the applicant in addition to themselves and any dependant family.

Source: V4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor and guidance on maintenance and accommodation provided by a third party in https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1112745/Visit_caseworker_guidance_12.pdf#page24

See also [What supporting documents should I include in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92740/what-supporting-documents-should-i-include-in-my-uk-visa-application)